# Sever-Side Java Charting library for Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, charts

Is there a server-side charting library for Google App Engine other than gwt-visualization or Google Charts?
Most of the libraries ( like JFreeCharts, JOpenCharts, EasyCharts, etc ) use the java.awt.* classes which are not supported by GAE.

I need to embed graphs generated by the server, in a pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my apps, I used to do charting server-side (JFreeCharts) but when I moved to app-engine I found it's way more convenient to send data to the client (json or other formats) and do charting in the browser with javascript instead of generating images server-side.

My favorite plotting library at the moment is [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/).

It'll save you money too, because you're not generating the images server side (computing time) and sending raw data instead of images (outgoing bandwidth).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am looking for something that can generate graphs at server. I need to publish the graphs on to a pdf file, so using a client side solution would not help.

Answer (score 1):

I am on the team here at [Zingchart](http://www.zingchart.com).  We have recently launched a server side version of our library.  This will allow you to create HTML5 charts on the server and include them in PDF's or as images.  Please feel free to get in contact with me if there is anything I might be able to help with.

-Jeff Frederich